# How to toggle the innerHTML of element on click

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, onclicklistener

How do I toggle an element's innerHTML on click with pure JS?

```
(function(){
    var div = document.getElementById("hook");

    div.addEventListener("click", function(){
        div.innerHTML = "I've been clicked";
    }, false);
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2UBs/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
(function(){
            var div = document.getElementById("hook");
            var curText = div.innerText;
            div.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if(this.innerText == curText){
                 div.innerText = "I've been clicked";
            }
            else{
                    div.innerText = curText;
            }
            }, false);

        })();
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/Z2UBs/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way (to show you the idea behind this):

```
    (function(){
        var div = document.getElementById("hook");

        div.addEventListener("click", function(){

            var state1 = document.getElementById('t1').value;
            var state2 = document.getElementById('t2').value;

            if ( div.innerHTML == state1 ) {
                div.innerHTML = state2;
            }
            else if ( div.innerHTML == state2 ) {
                div.innerHTML = state1;
            }
            // add as many dynamic values as you wish here
            else {
                // to be on the safe side
                div.innerHTML = state1;
            }
        }, false);

    })();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vnLS8/2/)

If you want it to be more efficient then introduce boolean variables for representing the current state.