# Hide text with the same button it opened it

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can I hide the text opened while clicking on a button by clicking on the same button ? In other words, the same button should show or hide a text when you click on it.

Here's my code that shows a text :

```
<h3> 
    <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()" ><img src="infoicon.png" height="30"></button>
                    <p id="infos"></p>

                    <script>
                        function myFunction() {
                            document.getElementById("infos").innerHTML = "blablabla";
                    }
                    </script>
</h3>
```

Comment: Could you add more detail here

Comment: [Use a validator](https://validator.w3.org/). You have machine detectable rrors in your HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to toggle the innerHTML of element on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499920/how-to-toggle-the-innerhtml-of-element-on-click) — Google “js toggle innerHTML”, click on the first few results.

Comment: do that with css display none function, write the text in your div box directly and toggle the visability state

Comment: Ok, sorry ! So, I'm trying to create an information icon on a website. I want this icon to show a text when you click on it and to hide the text when you click again. In this code, the icon is "infoicon.pgn" and the text is "blablabla".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a variable to save the button state

```js
var clicked = 0;
function myFunction() {
  if(clicked == 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("infos").innerHTML = "blablabla";
    clicked = 1;
  } else {
      document.getElementById("infos").innerHTML = "";
      clicked = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3> 
  <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()" ><img src="infoicon.png" height="30"></button>
  <p id="infos"></p>
</h3>
```

Comment: Maybe having a `data-opened` on the button would be better than having a variable?

Comment: I agree. using data attribute is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it worked for me:

```js
function showHide() {
  var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
  if (demo.innerHTML === "") {
    demo.innerHTML = "bla";
  } else {
    demo.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="showHide()">Show Hide</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Quite simple, using jQuery—

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {     
    $('#text-to-toggle').toggle(200);
});
```

Comment: The question isn’t about jQuery, [tag:jquery] wasn’t tagged.